Example where the last arrow in the sequence is not surjective.
Consider the exact sequence $0\rightarrow M'\rightarrow M\rightarrow M''\rightarrow0$ and its induced sequence $0\rightarrow T(M')\rightarrow T(M)\rightarrow T(M'')$, where $T$ denotes the torsion submodule. I aim to present an example where the last arrow is not surjective. Could it be that the sequence $0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow0$ satisfies this condition?
Since $T(\mathbb{Z})=0$ and $T(\mathbb{Q})=0$, and $T(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})\neq0$, the induced sequence becomes $0\rightarrow 0\rightarrow 0\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Also $0\to 2\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to0$

I think you meant to write the exact sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0.
$$
Since indeed $T(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ yet $T(\mathbb{Z}) = T(\mathbb{Q}) = 0$ this is a counterexample to the (right) exactness of the functor $T(-)$.

Perhaps one should explicitly note here that there is no exact sequence of the form $0 \to \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z} \to 0$: $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a submodule of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Of course, the sequence I wanted to write was $0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow0$
